# Need to extract all characters in a tag with BeautifulSoup or turn full tag into string

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, text-extraction

I need to turn `Tag` object or 'node' into string.
Here's my code:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
class scraping: 
    site = urllib.urlopen("http://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-36466228")           
    myfile = site.read()  
    soup = BeautifulSoup(myfile)  
    text = ""
    for node in soup.findAll("p"):        
        print node 
        #None of two lines are working
        #text.join(node)
        #text += node
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
text += str(node)
```

Comment: The problem is I want not only text, but I need everything, full tag as a string.

Comment: @FootAdministration so.. str(node)?

Comment: I need 'node' converted to a string and 'node' is a Tag, I dont want to extract text from Tag.

Comment: Thanks H. Lewroll!

Comment: should I delete this question when it is answered?

Comment: @FootAdministration you should accept the answer if it is good enough